# SlashDB error: 'ResultProxy' object has no attribute 'execution_options'

Tags: rest, slashdb

I have a SlashDB installation on top of MySQL. Once in a while, especially after a period of time of inactivity, the first call to an API returns:

```
'ResultProxy' object has no attribute 'execution_options'
```

The second request (same endpoint) would work normally.

My guess was that SlashDB's connection to MySQL had been terminated due to inactivity. I set the `wait_timeout` system variable (MySQL) to about 10 hours and it seems to help in some cases.

What does this error mean, and is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: This seems to be a Python error coming from sqlalchemy. Has anybody got any clue?

Comment: Please check this with version 1.0 (latest as of this writing).

Answer (score 1):

This should no longer occur in version 1.0, but in case you still have a problem please post a dump of your database schema with your question.